# Datetime function in Karate

Tags: java, datetime, karate

Need to insert datetime in my tests. This is what I tried:

**Datetime.java**

```
package com.org.unit.automation.utils;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
public class Datetime {  
    public static String getNowDate() {
        Date nowDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat nowDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'Z'");
        return nowDateFormat.format(nowDate);
    }
}
```

**sdf.feature**

```
Feature: Print current ISO datetime
  Background:
    * def Datetime = Java.type('com.org.unit.automation.utils.Datetime')
    * def date = new Datetime()
    * def effectiveDate = date.getNowDate()
    * print effectiveDate
```

**Result**

[ERROR]   KarateRunner.test:11 js failed:
01: date.getNowDate()
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (getNowDate) on com.resmed.patientcore.automation.utils.Datetime failed due to: Unknown identifier: getNowDate

Comment: You don't need to create an instance. You have a `static` method. You should probably be using `java.time` though

Comment: All you need is `return ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'Z'"));` And presumably `def effectiveDate = Datetime.getNowDate()`

Answer (score 2):

Solution thanks to g00se...

**Datetime.java**

```
package com.org.unit.automation.utils;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class Datetime {  
    public static String getNowDate() {
        return ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'Z'"));
    }
}
```

**sdf.feature**

```
Feature: Print current ISO datetime
  Background:
    * def Datetime = Java.type('com.org.unit.automation.utils.Datetime')
    * def effectiveDate = Datetime.getNowDate()
    * print effectiveDate
```

**Result**

"2023-06-23 10:45:50Z"

Comment: That's good but are you sure that sdf code is right?

Comment: Good eye. Fixed it